# What does \x00@ mean?

Tags: hex, byte, executable

I read an Executable file (exe) and I saw `\x00@`, I know that `0x00` is NULL, but what does the `@` represent in hexdecimal? I couldn't find any information about this.

### Example

`b'MZ\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x1f\xba\x0e\x00\xb4\t\xcd!\xb8\x01L\xcd!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.\r\r\n'`

Comment: In what context did you see this? Was this part of a string literal?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: @Lundin Please check my update

Comment: Sometimes a `'@'` is just a `'@'`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yeah but what does it mean?

Comment: As you can see at the part containing `This program...` not everything is escaped. Printable characters are shown as they are.

Comment: You are looking at some binary file. The meaning of the content is depending on the format specification. Check the specs for EXE files to see what a certain value in that location means. Also you must be aware that a `'@'` in any other location has totally different meaning.

Comment: @Gerhardh I know that strings are not converted into instructions cuz they don't need to, but the values you talkin about depends on the program's code, isn't it?

Comment: This appears to be the beginning of a Windows executable. The bulk of what you show there is the small stub DOS program that executes when you attempt to run the program on a system without Windows installed.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError So you are saying that when I read the binary on a Windows system it will not appear?

Comment: No, you can read all of it on any system. Go get the [Portable Executable Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#:~:text=This%20specification%20describes%20the%20structure,(COFF)%20files%2C%20respectively.) - it has the full dope on what you're looking at.

Comment: Probably you just need to get a better hex viewer/editor.

Comment: you're reading the file as string in python? just don't. Use a hex editor instead. And `MZ` is the signature of PE format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means nothing special, you are simply viewing raw binary in some manner of bad editor and `@` simply means value 0x40, or perhaps 0x0040. Perhaps the editor is using a symbol format (some UTF?) where most of these raw hex values don't make sense, but it was able to represent 0x40 or 0x0040 as @.

I'm guessing this binary goo is from the [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) for Windows executables.